# How do I override footer copyright text in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to customize `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer class` using custom module.

Output: **Hello World!**

**di.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer">
        <plugin name="footer-text-override" type="Hello\Test\Plugin\Footer" sortOrder="15" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Footer.php**

```
<?php

namespace Hello\Test\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Footer extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer
{
    public function getCopyright()
    {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: It can be edit in Admin configuration, why do you need to override it?

Comment: @SayTruth If you want to programmatically update the copyright year in PHP, you will need to override the class yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to override a class just to change the text? Magento provides a feature to change the text of footer.

> Go to: Admin > Content > Design > Configuration

Click on edit action of the store view. Now, scroll down the page and there is footer section, expand it and enter the text of you with in Copyright field.

**Save it and flush the cache.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works like charm!!

Answer (score 0):

To override footer copyright text in magento2, you can use **preference** instead of **plugin**.

So your di.xml is looks like following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" type="Hello\Test\Plugin\Footer" />
</config>
```

Preference is used for overriding class. It is similar to class rewrites in magento1.

Plugin allow us to execute our code before, after and around any public methods from the class. (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: With preference, where do you put the code file? From the example, it looks like you still place the files within the plugin folder? If so, why not just do a plugin to begin with?